# How to use Google Analytics to get a distribution of time on page for a specific set of pages?

Tags: google-analytics, user-engagement

Google Analytics provides a fairly comprehensive breakdown for **session** duration under Audience > Behavior > Engagement:

[image: session duration histogram - Google Analytics]

But I'm having trouble finding a similar GA view or other means of pulling data on the distribution of time on a single page or set of pages. All that's available is "Avg. Time on Page," which of course could be totally thrown off by a handful of extreme outliers.

Is there any way to break down this average into a distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Audience → Behavior → Engagement report can be applied to the visitors on a set of pages using advanced segments.

You need to create a segment for the users that visit the page in question:

1. Click "+ Add Segment"
2. Click "+ New Segment"
3. Name the new segment where it says "Segment name" (eg "home page visitors")
4. Click on "Advanced" "Conditions"
5. Click on the "Ad Content" drop down and change it to "Landing page"
6. Set it to "exactly match" the page you are interested in (eg "/" for the home page)
7. Save your segment
8. See that report for only the users who landed on the page in question.

Comment: Advanced segments is the jquery of Google Analytics

Comment: That and "motion charts".   One of those two will answer half the GA questions we get here.

Comment: Shouldn't it be only `Page`? `Landing page` is only for when the user arrives on your site through that page, right?

Comment: Wait, this is not the *time on a single page or a set of pages* as the user wants -- it's still the original *total session time*, isn't it? So I guess this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve similar results in Google Analytics 4? (sorry for resurrecting such an old post)

Comment: You should ask that as a new question.